# What test of independence of sample proportions is appropriate when n is very large and p is very small?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric, independence, proportion

I have the (not necessarily veridical) impression that typical textbook independence tests of proportions are intended for use the proportions involved are not super small.

In my case n may be 10^8 but the count of successes may be 10^4.

N per group may also differ, which of course means the sample variances for sample proportions differ.

How can I test for the independence of two sample proportions when sample size is large and the sample proportions are very small?

Comment: The textbooks usually are clear that the scope of validity of these tests depends on the *counts* rather than the proportions. With $N=10^8$ and $p=10^{-4}$, the counts will be around $10^4$, which is quite large indeed.  (I do presume you mean $10^{-4}$ and not $10^4$.)

Comment: Yes, I mean count of success = 10^4

Comment: FWIW the Khan Academy video on two sample proportion tests does say "small proportions", not "small counts"

Comment: I am surprised that anybody would take those videos as being authoritative.

Comment: Thus the "FWIW" prefix. Maybe I should be surprised by politeness around here